# In QT,how to distinguish debug and release in someway like preprocessor

Tags: qt, debugging, preprocessor, release

I know we can use #if DEBUG #else #endif in c#,so i think Qt has the same way to do that, like this：

```
QString Paths::sqlScriptPath()
{
#if DEBUG
    return "D:\edocclient\edocclient-build-Desktop_Qt_4_8_4_QT4_8_4-Debug\sql";
#else
    return "D:\edocclient\edocclient-build-Desktop_Qt_4_8_4_QT4_8_4-Release\sql";
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Similar Question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714118/detect-if-qt-is-running-a-debug-build-at-runtime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct Qt macros for that is `QT_DEBUG`. So you code will be:

```
QString Paths::sqlScriptPath()
{
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
    return "D:\edocclient\edocclient-build-Desktop_Qt_4_8_4_QT4_8_4-Debug\sql";
#else
    return "D:\edocclient\edocclient-build-Desktop_Qt_4_8_4_QT4_8_4-Release\sql";
#endif
}
```